# create knex queryBuilder and execute later

Tags: javascript, sql, promise

I'm hoping to create a queryBuilder object, and defer execution until I'm ready. The following code allows me to pass a queryBuilder object between functions without executing the query.

```
const getQueryBuilder = () => 
    knex({ client: "mysql2" }).queryBuilder();

const getBaseSelect = () =>
    getQueryBuilder().select().from('foo');

const getOne = () =>
   getBaseSelect().limit(1);

console.log(getBaseSelect()); // select * from `foo`
console.log(getOne());        // select * from `foo` limit 1
```

My question is how do I then execute the query that I've constructed in the queryBuilder?

Or is there a better way to construct queries from multiple synchronous functions before executing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'defer execution until' you are 'ready.'

It will depend on what you mean by 'ready', but you can fire the query when the desired action is finished using `Promise`.

For example, if you want to execute the query after 5 seconds delay, using the example from [MDN Promise doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise), you can do something like this:

```js
let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was successful, and reject(...) when it failed.
  // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code.
  // In reality, you will probably be using something like XHR or an HTML5 API.
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve("After this value is resolved with 5000ms delay, "); // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 5000);
});

myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
  // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
  // You can fire your query here
  console.log(successMessage + "you can execute your query inside this then(..) function!");
  // execute(getBaseSelect());
});
```

If you are waiting on multiple promises, you can use `Promise.all(..)` like this:

```
Promise.all([myFirstPromise, mySecondPromise, myThirdPromise])
  .then((values) => {
    return execute(values[0], values[1], values[2])
  });
```