# Using knex as a queryBuilder only

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, knex.js, squel.js

I have been using squel as query builder for our project and have to migrate due to it being outdated and vulnerable. The squel doc suggested to use knex, I have bit of trouble trying to use it simply just as querybuilder, as database we are using snowflake and use the native sdk.

If someone could help me with a basic insert query in knex without connection creation.
Also the feature/ability to something similar like below in knex.

```
const insertQuery: squel.Insert = squel
            .insert()
            .into('TENANT')
            .set('URI', 'dummy')
            .set('CREATEDBY', 'ADMIN');

 if (uuid != null) {
      insertQuery.set('UUID', uuid);
 }
```

so basically create the query dynamically and later pass it snowflake query, values.

Any leads would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @xanld can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are asking for!

```js
        const insertQuery = squel.Insert = squel
                    .insert()
                    .into('TENANT')
                    .set('URI', 'dummy')
                    .set('CREATEDBY', 'ADMIN');

        let sqlNative = insertQuery.toSQL().toNative()
        //this is the sql in the format sent to the SQL driver.
        console.log(sqlNative)
         if (uuid != null) {
              insertQuery.set('UUID', uuid);
         }
```

https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2378

Comment: You are still using squel, i want to use knex and migrate away from squel. Squel is outdated and is prone to sql injection and has no contribution from last 2 years. Select from knex is used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500288/create-knex-querybuilder-and-execute-later

Comment: Knex actually handles the risk of injection attacks for you through prepared statements. The only way you can have a query that is unprepared for injection attacks is if you use the .raw() methods. Then you need to prepare the queries yourself. However knex only currently supports:
MySQL
postgreSQL,
Amazon Redshift,
SQLite3,
Oracle,
MSSQL

It is also specifically an SQL query builder which is stated in the first paragraph of their documentation. 

https://knexjs.org/